# getting position from window

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to get a left position in pixel from the window using jquery 
I am attaching the image.

I am using a responsive grid I don't have a fixed with for divs
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using `offset`? http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery [`offset`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) function should give you what you want.

```
var left = $('#mydivid').offset().left;
```

Working example - http://jsfiddle.net/d25fu/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
<p></p>



<script>
var p = $("p:last");
var offset = p.offset();
p.html( "left: " + offset.left + ", top: " + offset.top );
</script>
```

Comment: it is fetching the distance from the parent div I have tried this

Comment: thanks it is correct. but the when I am reducing browser zoom (ctrl+-)
it is not coming properly it is adding some pixel extra

Comment: yes it will,if page size increases,the space will probably increase

Comment: not like that the pixel is not proper it is showing me 242px but I have checked with Photoshop, it is showing only 193px.

Answer (score 0):

.offset() will return the offset position of an element as a simple object, eg:

```
var position = $(element).offset(); // position = { left: 42, top: 567 }
```

You can use this return value to position other elements at the same spot:

```
$(anotherElement).css(position)
```